# Opening geo: links in Google Sheets on Mobile

Tags: google-maps, android-intent, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with `geo:` links in it.

I would like to make it into a hyperlink so that when I click/tap on it (then `Follow link` on mobile) it will **open the maps app** (e.g. Google Maps, OsmAnd, Maps.me, etc)

I tried for example, `=HYPERLINK("geo:40.689244,-74.044514?z=21", "Location")` but Google Sheets refuses to make it into a link.

Any help on how to do this, even with the use of Google Apps Script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because it is not yet fully supported by Android and most probably by Google APIs. See [Reference of Available Intents](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/app-intents.html).

> The Geo URI scheme (not fully supported) is currently under development.